# Strange boost program_options issue using boost vector and string

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

Using Boost.Program_options, I have code along the lines of as follows:

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;
namespace ct = boost::container;
```

And in a particular function:

```
Options opts;
ct::string fname;
ct::vector<ct::string> others;

{   po::options_description general("General");
    general.add_options()
        ("version,v", "Print version information")
        ("help,h", "Show help message")
        ("verbosity,V", po::value(&opts.verbosity)->default_value(0)->value_name("level"), "Runtime noise")
        ("main-is,m", po::value(&fname)->default_value("Main.pbc")->value_name("fname"), "Program filename")
        /* error */ ("sideload,l", po::value<ct::vector<ct::string> >(&others)->multitoken(), "Other modules")
        ;

    po::options_description performance("Performance");
    performance.add_options()
        // ... code removed here ...
        ;

    po::positional_options_description modules;
    modules.add("main-is", 1).add("sideload", -1);

    po::options_description cmdline;
    cmdline.add(general).add(performance);

    po::variables_map vm;
    try {
        po::store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(cmdline).positional(modules).run(), vm);
        po::notify(vm);
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (vm.count("help") || argc == 1) {
        version();
        std::cout << std::endl << "USAGE: " << argv[0] << " [options] MAIN.pbc [sideload modules ...]" << std::endl;
        std::cout << cmdline << std::endl;
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    if (vm.count("version")) {
        version();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

I get an error which looks like this:

```
In file included from /Users/kvanb/git/panthera/panthera/src/main.cpp:7:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:13:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/program_options/value_semantic.hpp:14:
/usr/local/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:388:13: error: static_assert failed "Target type is
      neither std::istream`able nor std::wistream`able"
  ...BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG((result_t::value || boost::has_right_shift<std::basic_istream<wchar_t>, T >::value), 
     ^                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If I comment out the line I've commented `/* error */` above, it goes away.

I've tried using `std::vector` and `std::string` instead, but the error remains the same.

Ideas?

Comment: Interesting. It works fine with a `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: I'll give it one more quick shot, but I'm certain it didn't work a moment ago.

Comment: Huh -- you're right. That's .. strange. Sorry.

Comment: I'm curious about the error, though I didn't read through the full message. `std::vector` and `boost::container::vector` are both not streamable, and `std::string` and `boost::container::string` both are.

Comment: It's indeed very curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porgram Options apparently doesn't support Boost Container's `boost::container::vector` type for multi-value options.

You can use `std::vector<ct::string>`, or look for which trait to specialize to support `ct::vector` as well

E.g. in `boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp` you'd need to add overloads for `boost::container::vector`:

```
/** Validates sequences. Allows multiple values per option occurrence
    and multiple occurrences. */
template<class T, class charT>
void validate(boost::any& v, 
              const std::vector<std::basic_string<charT> >& s, 
              boost::conatainer::vector<T>*, // HERE!
              int)
```

Honestly, as you can see they didn't even support `std::vector` with custom allocators. I think the devs won't be eager to implement this; the implementation is complicated enough as it is (with the overloads being tweaked to allow for compilers that don't do *partial ordering* of template instantiations correctly).